# Extract data from API Object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API with the following JSON output and I have a function in react that I call.

I can see the api output in console.log(users) so the data is being passed into the function.

I am trying to output the array contained in "data" but can't seem to access the data.

```
{
  "dataCount": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Test review header",
      "text": "This is  adescription for a test review",
      "img": "http://pngimg.com/upload/pigeon_PNG3423.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test review header2",
      "text": "This is  adescription for a test review2",
      "img": "http://pngimg.com/upload/pigeon_PNG3422.png"
    }
  ]
}

renderUsers() {

    const { users } = this.props;

    console.log(users);

    Object.keys(users).map(name => users[name])
        console.log(users[name]);
    };
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide (a part) of the object you receive from the api?

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer, In chrome it appears as an Object and I'm trying to access the data array within this object

Comment: is users the above JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you need to iterate over is present in the `data` field of users.

When you are using `lists` you have to specify the `key` property, to make react keep track of each item in list.

```
renderUsers() {
  const { users } = this.props;
  return (
    <ul>
     { 
        users.data.map(name => {
            <li key={name}>users[name]</li>
        }) 
     }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: This works fine when I attempt to access http://api.github.com/users but when I hit my own api I get caught (in promise) TypeError: users.map is not a function, presumably because map is not available on an object?

Comment: or I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't use react but what you want should be the same in other javascript frameworks.

**Are you sure that it is JSON you receive?**

We need to be sure that you receive a JSON object and not normal text. Lets say you have a function `parseResponse(data)`. We can call `JSON.parse(data)` to parse the data param to a json object. It is also possible that you store the result in a variable.

**Using the JSON object**

When we are sure you have the param parsed to a JSON object, we get it's data. For example, if you want to get the name of the first object in data, you can call:
`parsedJson.data[0].name`
where parsedJson is the result of `JSON.parse(data)`,
data is an array of objects in the JSON,
`0` is the first object in the array

It is possible that you have this kind of function then:

```
function parseResponse(data) {
  var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < parsedJson.data.length; i++) {
      console.log(parsedJson.data[i].name);
  }
}
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLk04cmw/)